# Defining a group of objects

Tags: ios, objective-c, object

Is there anyway to group objects?

Say for example I have UIImageView1, UIImageView2, and UIImageView3 and I want to hide them all... do I have to type EVERY TIME

```
UIImageView1.hidden = YES;
UIImageView2.hidden = YES;
UIImageView3.hidden = YES;
```

Or is there anyway that I can define a group and just say `group1.hidden = YES;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use Key-Value Coding:

```
NSArray *imageViews = @[imageView1, imageView2, imageView3];
[imageViews setValue:@YES forKey:@"hidden"];
```

This works because calling `setValue:forKey:` on an `NSArray` invokes `setValue:forKey:` on each of the array's items.

Answer (score 2):

you must add 3 imageView to a parentView and then

foreach (UIView *view in parentView.subViews)
{

if([view isMemberOf:[UIImageView class]])

{

```
    [view setHidden:YES];
```

}
}

by other way you can add tag for each imageView above and get it to setHidden